# Why is my Perl loop off by one at the end?

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

I have this program which does not work as expected. Help me.

I want to print a row heading.

If input is `4`, I want `1|2|3|4` to be output.

It does not work as all, if I hard-code `$count` value it works partially but the last number is missing.

```
sub printC {
        my $count = @_;
        # count = 4  # works partially only prints 1|2|3
        for(my $i=1;$i<$count;$i++) {
                print "$i|";
        }
        print $i;
}
$count  = 2;
&printC($count);
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
my $count = @_;
```

The assignment is happening in a *scalar* context which assigns the number of elements in array `@_` to `$count`, which your case is `1`, as you are passing `1` argument to the function.

To fix this you can do:

```
my ($count) = @_;
```

or

```
my $count = $_[0];
```

here is another problem:

```
for(my $i=1.....
    ^^
```

By using `my` you've made `$i` *local* to the body of `for` and it'll not be available *outside* it. So your final `print` outside the `for` is not printing anything. To fix this move the declaration of `$i` outside the loop:

```
sub printC {
        my ($count) = @_;
        my $i;
        ....
```

Always make it a point to write

```
use strict;
```

at the top of your program which enables you to catch such bugs.

The *perl way* of doing what your function does is:

```
print join('|',1..$count);
```

Answer (score 5):

A real Perl hacker might write something like this:

```
sub printC {
  my $count = shift;
  print join "|", (1 .. $count);
}
```

Once you understand how this works, you'll find you've learned some more about Perl. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`$i` does not exist once you've left the `for` loop because of where it's declared.

You could do

```
sub printC {
    my ($count) = @_;
    my $i;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        print "$i|";
    }
    print $i;
}
```

Even simpler:

```
sub printC {
    my ($count) = @_;
    print join("|", 1 .. $count) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other bit of "being more Perlish" is to not use the C-style `for` loop.  There is almost *never* a need to use a C-style `for` in Perl.

Instead of

```
for(my $i=1;$i<$count;$i++) { ... }
```

use

```
for my $i (1 .. $count) { ... }
```

They're *almost* equivalent, except the latter version is both more easily readable and more resistant to off-by-one errors.  (The reason your code was only printing `1|2|3` instead of `1|2|3|4` is because the test in your C-style `for` was checking `$i<$count` when it should have been `$i<=$count` - this is a very common mistake with C-style `for` loops which `for (list)` avoids completely.)

Also, don't prefix your sub calls with `&`.  It's a holdover from Perl 4 which is no longer needed in Perl 5 and has side effects which you probably aren't aware of and probably don't want.  Just use `printC($count)` instead of `&printC($count)`.

But, yeah, in this particular case, `join` is probably a better approach than `for` anyhow.